# Longer subtitles in MapView annotations (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkpointannotation

I have a mapView with annotations displaying titles and subtitles. The subtitles are sometimes longer than the width of the annotation, so I am wondering if i can make them multiline?
It's coded like this so far:

```
func annotate(newCoordinate, title: String, subtitle: String) {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
    annotation.title = title
    annotation.subtitle = subtitle
    self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)    
}
```

Then i have a few options set in

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {...}
```

which are not relevant here.

Is it posible to make a custom annotation view?
I've tried a couple of things, but nothing worked. The closest I can get is adding a button to display the longer subtitle separately, but i'd rather have it inside the annotation.

Is it possible?

Comment: plz see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831382/how-to-display-2-lines-of-text-for-subtitle-of-mkannotation-and-change-the-image

Comment: for swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446219/swift-2-multiline-mkpointannotation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out, I added a label in viewForAnnotation and it just worked

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    //THIS IS THE GOOD BIT
    let subtitleView = UILabel()
    subtitleView.font = subtitleView.font.fontWithSize(12)
    subtitleView.numberOfLines = 0
    subtitleView.text = annotation.subtitle!
    pinView!.detailCalloutAccessoryView = subtitleView


    return pinView
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but "detailCalloutAccessoryView" is available since 9.0