# Adding Custom UIView to TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitableview

I have been unsuccessful in adding my custom UIView to my TableViewCell. This custom view represents a custom check mark for each table view cell. I am doing my project without a storyboard and I'm not sure how to add this custom UIView to my UITableViewCell programmatically. Here's my code:

```
class CheckBoxView: UIView {

var isChecked: Bool
var checkBoxImageView: UIImageView
var checkBoxChanged :() -> () = { }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.isChecked = false
    self.checkBoxImageView = UIImageView(image: nil)

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setup()
}

func setup() {

    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    self.checkBoxImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: 25, height: 25)
    self.addSubview(self.checkBoxImageView)

    let selector: Selector = "checkBoxTapped"

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

}

func checkBoxTapped() {
    self.checkBoxChanged()
}

func markAsChecked() {
    self.checkBoxImageView.image = UIImage(named: "new_message_icon")
}

func markAsUnChecked() {
    self.checkBoxImageView.image = nil
}

}
```

Here's my TableViewCell:

```
class AddContactsCell: UITableViewCell {

let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView
}()

let checkBox: CheckBoxView = {
    let view = UIView() as! CheckBoxView
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return view
}()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    textLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: textLabel!.frame.origin.y - 2, width: textLabel!.frame.width, height: textLabel!.frame.height)

    detailTextLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: 101, y: detailTextLabel!.frame.origin.y + 1, width: detailTextLabel!.frame.width, height: detailTextLabel!.frame.height)
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    addSubview(profileImageView)
    self.addSubview(checkBox)

    //ios 9 constraint anchors
    //need x,y,width,height anchors
    profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    checkBox.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    checkBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    checkBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    checkBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

I would really appreciate if you could tell me where I'm going wrong with adding the UIView.

Comment: Where is your `cellForRow` method?

Comment: Fangming Ning it's in my table but I didn't post it because it's a lot of code

Comment: Ok. So your image view is added correctly but not your custom view, right?

Comment: exactly. my custom view gives this error: Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x107439f40) to 'chatApplication.CheckBoxView'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should instanciate your `CheckBoxView` and not cast a normal `UIView` to your CheckBoxView

change this line:

```
let view = UIView() as! CheckBoxView
```

to this line

```
let view = CheckBoxView()
```

Comment: it asks for let view = CheckBoxView(coder: <#NSCoder#>) but i'm not sure what to put in the coder. I used a tutorial to set this up so i'm not 100% familiar with how the code is working

Comment: then you add an `init` also without an coder with your `CheckBoxView`

Comment: i'm a bit unfamiliar with that. can you give an example of the code. i would really appreciate it

Comment: please use the Stackoverview/Google search! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056864/swift-subclass-uiview

Comment: keywords: subclass uiview